# How to identify if an object holds a null value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a control on a form (text box) which references an underlying table. I would like to have a command which upon clicking updates the null value to the value "not started".  Upon clicking, I get a run time error message of 424 - Object necessary.

```
Private Sub Comando50_Click()

  If [txtScope] = ("not started") Then
      [txtScope] = ("proposed")

  ElseIf [txtScope] = ("proposed") Then
      [txtScope] = ("accepted")

  ElseIf [txtScope] Is Null Then
      [txtScope] = ("not started")


  ElseIf [txtScope] = ("accepted") Then
      [txtScope] = ("rejected")


  ElseIf [txtScope] = ("rejected") Then
       [txtScope] = ("on track")

  ElseIf [txtScope] = ("on track") Then
      [txtScope] = ("needs attention")


  ElseIf [txtScope] = ("needs attention") Then
      [txtScope] = ("critical")

  ElseIf [txtScope] = ("critical") Then
      [txtScope] = ("complete")

  ElseIf [txtScope] = ("complete") Then
      [txtScope] = ("not started")

  End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming txtScope is a Textbox or Field on your form, then you should refer to it as such:

Me.txtScope

Or

Me!txtScope

You don't need to put parentheses around your text values:

```
Private Sub Comando50_Click()

  If Me.txtScope = "not started" Then
      Me.txtScope = "proposed"    
  ElseIf Me.txtScope = "proposed" Then
      Me.txtScope = "accepted"
'etc etc
End Sub
```

Comment: Its still not picking up the null values however.  Could it be because the object actually comes from a drop down menu?

Comment: ElseIf Me.txtScope = Null Then
    Me.txtScope = ("not started")